# How can i resolve DXGI_FORMAT compatibility issues?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I want to use a compute shader for post processing. So the idea is to set the CS output to the back buffer. Which as far as i know means using a UAV. But the back buffer uses BGRA. So this:

```cpp
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pBackBuffer;
pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), &pBackBuffer);

D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uav_desc;
uav_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;// BGRA!
uav_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
uav_desc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11UnorderedAccessView> pUnorderedAccessView;
pDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(
    pBackBuffer.Get(),
    &uav_desc,
    &pUnorderedAccessView);
```

Generates an error: The format (0x57, B8G8R8A8_UNORM) cannot be used with a Typed Unordered Access View.

And if I try to change the format to a compatible one as per [MDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ff471325(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```cpp
...
uav_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;// RGBA!
...
```

Generates an error: The Format (0x1c, R8G8B8A8_UNORM) is invalid, when creating a View; the Resource was already created with a fully qualified Format, which is not castable (0x57, B8G8R8A8_UNORM).

The thing is I don't care what the format is, as it can be fixed inside the compute shader!

Is there a way to bypass this? Or maybe not use a UAV for CS output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a subset of UAV formats are supported for loading/storing, which is why the BGRA format fails.

The logic is encoded in this helper function:

```
// typedUAVLoadAdditionalFormats is the value obtained from D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS.TypedUAVLoadAdditionalFormats

    bool FormatIsUAVCompatible(_In_ ID3D12Device* device, bool typedUAVLoadAdditionalFormats, DXGI_FORMAT format) noexcept
    {
        switch (format)
        {
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32_SINT:
            // Unconditionally supported.
            return true;

        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8_SINT:
            // All these are supported if this optional feature is set.
            return typedUAVLoadAdditionalFormats;

        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R11G11B10_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_FLOAT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_SNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_SNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_SINT:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R16_SNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_R8_SNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_A8_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_B5G6R5_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_B5G5R5A1_UNORM:
        case DXGI_FORMAT_B4G4R4A4_UNORM:
            // Conditionally supported by specific devices.
            if (typedUAVLoadAdditionalFormats)
            {
                D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_FORMAT_SUPPORT formatSupport = { format, D3D12_FORMAT_SUPPORT1_NONE, D3D12_FORMAT_SUPPORT2_NONE };
                if (SUCCEEDED(device->CheckFeatureSupport(D3D12_FEATURE_FORMAT_SUPPORT, &formatSupport, sizeof(formatSupport))))
                {
                    const DWORD mask = D3D12_FORMAT_SUPPORT2_UAV_TYPED_LOAD | D3D12_FORMAT_SUPPORT2_UAV_TYPED_STORE;
                    return ((formatSupport.Support2 & mask) == mask);
                }
            }
            return false;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
```

There is no BGRA format on that list other than the 16pp ones (which don't have RGB versions).

To support BGRA you use an alias texture in the same memory location as an RGBA UAV so you can reinterpret the data. This *only* works robustly if the device supports `D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_64KB_STANDARD_SWIZZLE` (i.e. you have to check `D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS.StandardSwizzle64KBSupported`). Unfortunately, not all devices support this.

See *DirectX Tool Kit for DX12*'s CS-based mipmap generation code `GenerateMips_TexturePathBGR` in [ResourceUpload.cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Src/ResourceUploadBatch.cpp).

**In short,** if the device doesn't support `D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS.StandardSwizzle64KBSupported`, I can't generate mipmaps for these formats: `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`, `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM`, `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM_SRGB`, `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM_SRGB` due to the fact that UAV doesn't support BGRA.

> On Xbox it's a UMA architecture and I know for a fact that RGBA/BGRA are laid out the same way in memory, therefore the validation doesn't prevent the alias on that platform. Some older PC drivers let you do it without a problem with `D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN`, but the modern versions of the validation layer prevent doing this at runtime.

> For some limited scenarios, you could try using `D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR`, but it is very slow and has a lot of [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/ne-d3d12-d3d12_texture_layout) which made it not useful for *DirectX Tool Kit for DX12*.